# Getting blank page when forcing HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, redirect, https

I was trying to force all my http requests to https using :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{www.advisorcircuit.com}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

But i am getting a blank page when i hit my site even thoughi can see my short cut icon on window tab. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Check the error log

Answer (score 0):

`%{..}` represents a variable.  I'm assuming `www.advisorcircuit.com` isn't a variable.

You'd either need:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.advisorcircuit.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```